# Como setar um atributo pelo nome dele contido numa variável?

Tags: javascript

**Por exemplo**

```
var attr = 'background';
elemento.style.attr = 'blue';
```

O problema é que quando eu passo a instrução da segunda linha, o JS entende que eu busco o atributo "`attr`" no `style` do `elemento`, quando o que eu quero é o valor "background" que está contido na variável `attr`.

Eu queria que o código fosse interpretado assim: `elemento.style.background = 'blue';`

Como posso fazer para que pegue o valor da variável `attr`, ao invés do nome dela?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var attr = 'background';
elemento.style[attr] = 'blue';
```

Que também é equivalente a...

```
var attr = 'background';
elemento['style'][attr] = 'blue';
```

Comment: Dessa eu não sabia! Obrigado!